# Why not start the GTA SA

Tags: wine, games, debian

I decided to drive his old gentleman in the GTA, before on Windows XP all summer and it was just a supper, but after install Linux stopped playing. So what I decided to set the GTA through Wine and eventually get what you see in the screenshots, the game runs but nothing happens after the download. Somebody faced such problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to wine hq you should be able to run gta sa pretty fine

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3780

I suggest to install game with help of "play on linux", it will set up all required settings for your game.